# Removing and adding items from a linked list (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

The code I wrote does not work when I try out the test cases but I can't understand why. My code is inside the 2 methods. If you need the rest of the class files you can find them here https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/hw/hw3/.
Note I edited the node class and created set and get methods. Could that be giving me errors or is my solution just wrong?

```
/**
*  squish() takes this list and, wherever two or more consecutive items are
*  equals(), it removes duplicate nodes so that only one consecutive copy
*  remains.  Hence, no two consecutive items in this list are equals() upon
*  completion of the procedure.
*
*  After squish() executes, the list may well be shorter than when squish()
*  began.  No extra items are added to make up for those removed.
*
*  For example, if the input list is [ 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 3 3 3 1 1 0 ], the
*  output list is [ 0 1 0 3 1 0 ].
*
*  IMPORTANT:  Be sure you use the equals() method, and not the "=="
*  operator, to compare items.
**/

public void squish() {
// Fill in your solution here.  (Ours is eleven lines long.)
  SListNode previous = head;
  SListNode next;
  SListNode root = head;
  int x = 1;

  for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
  {
      next = previous.getNext();
      if (!previous.equals(next))
      {
          root.setNext(next);
          root = next;
          x++;
      }
      previous = previous.getNext();

  }
  size = x;
}

/**
*  twin() takes this list and doubles its length by replacing each node
*  with two consecutive nodes referencing the same item.
*
*  For example, if the input list is [ 3 7 4 2 2 ], the
*  output list is [ 3 3 7 7 4 4 2 2 2 2 ].
*
*  IMPORTANT:  Do not try to make new copies of the items themselves.
*  Make new SListNodes, but just copy the references to the items.
**/

public void twin() {
 // Fill in your solution here.  (Ours is seven lines long.)
 SListNode previous = head;
 SListNode next;

 for (int counter = 0; counter < size; counter++)
 {
     next = previous.getNext();
     previous.setNext(previous);
     previous = previous.getNext();
     previous.setNext(next);
 }
 size = 2*size;
}
```

Comment: No I just want to learn something in my spare time...
Thanks you are a big help

Comment: The code inside the 2 methods on this page is and is incorrect. The rest of it is not. I already mentioned this. Also why are you being a jerk. It is the end of school year. It is not going to be numbered homework 3 if it was. I am not trying to cheat or anything like that. It is literally me trying to learn something in my spare time

Comment: Here look for yourself https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/61b/
The course is online for everyone and it has a different instructor at this time I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a problem on the list length not getting updated upon completion. The test cases might look for that and print out an error message when you forget to do that! (No biscuits!)

I'm not sure though, but it seems to be the most plausible explanation (looking at the test file and seeing how they explicitly stated that they check all invariants).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't want a solution. It is not for school but I am just practicing and there won't be a point in me practicing if you gave me the solution.

Comment: On second thoughts I think I have posted too hastily. The logic *should* work - I'm going through the class file to see if this is caused by something else.

Comment: The set and get I added look like this

  public SListNode getNext()
  {
      return next;
  }
  
  ,public void setNext (SListNode inNext)
  {
      next = inNext;
  }

Comment: That doesn't seem in anyway strange. Hmm, can you share the output you get for an example input?

Comment: Ahh! I just realized - I think there might be a checker on list size upon completion which you didn't update! I updated my answer.

Comment: I added size = size*2 in the twin method as a last line. Added x++ inside the if in the squish and at the bottom of it I added size = size - x, x was initialized to 0. Still getting the same output

Comment: Try changing the last line in squish to ```size = x```, and initialize ```x=1```. You should be able to see what's wrong with the counting :) oh also, in case they include a corner case when they give you an empty list, you should handle that too with an if statement or something equivalent...

Comment: Ah, that was really stupid of me. But I am still getting the same thing. Both the twin and the squish don't work. I edited my post with those lines included. I am just going to make my own Linked list class and see if it will work with the case they have. If I am doing something wrong I think I will find out then for sure

Comment: Hmm, I think you should just test a few cases for yourself, without using their test file. Edit main() and create a few lists and print them out to see whether it is doing what you want them to do!

Comment: Tested the first case with the classes I made and it worked! Thanks a lot! I was probably going to try for hours and hours  until I gave up or started doing my own classes

Comment: Well it might have been an outdated problem set with a faulty test suite! Glad it worked though, good luck with your exams!